# Python: signature with Numba

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I have a function that is doing some computation and at a certain point is calling another one. For example, the main function is something like:

```
import numba

@numba.njit(some signature here)
def my_funct():
    ...
    value = cosd(angle)
```

Since the function `cosd` is inside another function decorated with `numba.njit`, it has to be decorated as well, and in my case it is:

```
from numba import float64

@numba.njit(float64(float64))
def cosd(angle):
    return np.cos(np.radians(angle))
```

My problem now is that in another function, the input value `angle` is an array and the related output is an array as well. I know that I could decorate my function as `@numba.njit(float64[:](float64[:]))` but doing so the function would not accept scalars anymore. How can I can tell `numba` that input is something like `Union[float64, float64[:]]`? Of course this applies to the output as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In most cases you don't have to specify types. Numba will determine them the first time you call the function. If you are interested in the types you can call `my_funct.nopython_signatures` to see what was detected.

Comment: @max9111 thanks for your comment. I just started using ```numba``` so I am not an expert but I noticed that in general with signatures the compilation is faster and so my code is faster. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found an answer myself.
The solution is to create a list of signatures so, for my example, it would be:

```
from numba import float64

@njit([float64(float64), float64[:](float64[:])])
def cosd(angle):
    return np.cos(np.radians(angle))
```

I hope this will be helpful to others.